# What ability score modifier does a javelin's damage use?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, damage, ability-scores

I'm making a character, and this part always had me confused, so a friend helped me but never explained.

When you do your weapon damage, like 1d12 + 4, you use your Strength modifier for the damage bonus of 4. But what ability do you use for javelins - is it Dexterity or Strength?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour], and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: BTW, you don't always use strength for weapon damage, as you said in the question. It is strength or dexterity based on the weapon.

Answer (score 19):

### You use strength

This is spelled out in the Basic Rules where it describes the [Thrown weapon property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) (**emphasis** mine):

> If a weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon to make a ranged attack. If the weapon is a melee weapon, **you use the same ability modifier for that attack roll and damage roll that you would use for a melee attack with the weapon.**

The modifier you use for a melee attack with a javelin is strength (can also be found in the Basic Rules in the [Combat section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#AttackRolls)):

> **Ability Modifier.** The ability modifier used for a melee weapon attack is Strength

Since you would have been making a melee weapon attack with Strength, the Thrown property causes you to continue to use Strength, even though it's a ranged attack in this instance.

Comment: @Vylix I'm more worried that a person may not know where to find the rule for what to use with a melee attack in general. I added a clarifying paragraph instead,

Comment: It took us a few months into our 5e sessions in 2014 to grok that the jav used str for damage and hit boost. Not an uncommon issue when coming from other editions.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast which editions used Dex for javelins?

Comment: 3e/3.5/Pathfinder all used Dex for to-hit with all ranged attacks (I think one of them had a feat allowing you to use Str for to-hit with thrown weapons specifically), I think 4e did as well but my 4e experience is pretty limited.  They used Str for damage for thrown weapons (and composite bows) but Dex to hit...

Comment: @András In the original game there was a +1 to hit for missile weapons with a 13+ dex.  The details varied with editions, see gatherer's comment.

Comment: I think the point of confusion is the part "*If the weapon is a melee weapon, you use the same ability modifier*". Since the javelin is not really a melee weapon, the phrasing may make it sound like there would be some special rule. In that regard, Ben's answer is actually clearer, by making a distinction between *ranged* weapons and *thrown* ones.

Answer (score 16):

### Javelins use Strength.

Basically, Strength is the ability you use for calculating hit/damage, unless otherwise specified. For example, the Monk can use their Strength, or Dexterity, as they see fit:

> You can use Dexterity instead of Strength for the attack and damage rolls of your unarmed strikes and monk weapons.

[Source](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#ClassFeatures)

Or the finesse property, again allows you to use Strength, or Dex (the dagger, and darts have this property, for example):

> **Finesse.** When making an attack with a finesse weapon, you use your choice of your Strength or Dexterity modifier for the attack and damage rolls. You must use the same modifier for both rolls.

[Source](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties)

The important thing to differentiate is that **Ranged** weapons use Dex, and **Thrown** weapons use Strength (unless they have the "Finesse" property, as explained above).